# Python string similarity (with complexity)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, search, levenshtein-distance

I have a string I would like to match against a list of candidates. Here is an example:

```
# ignore case
string = "The Shining" # The Stanley Kubrick Movie
candidates = ['Shining', 'The shins', 'Shining, The'] 
most_similar(string, candidates)
==> 'Shining, The'
```

Doing a "literal string comparison", I usually use the [Levenshtein distance](https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/) or ratio in this case. However, I'd like to do a more sophisticated similarity test so that the best match in the above case is `Shining, The`.

I'm guessing that this is a common issue that has probably been solved extensively, so I was wondering what library/tool/etc. might be the best way to get what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) or [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) package.

In this specific case, you're probably leaning towards `fuzzywuzzy` since you are just trying to do a string match.

`gensim` is more for calculating similarity scores and vector representations for documents, paragraphs, sentences, words, corpora, etc... with the goal of capturing semantic/topical meaning rather than literal string matching.

So in your case, using fuzzy string matching, you might do:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

fuzz.partial_ratio('Shining', 'The shins')
>>> 50 

fuzz.partial_ratio('Shining', 'Shining, The')
>>> 100

fuzz.partial_ratio('Shining', 'unrelated')
>>> 14
```

The `partial_ratio` function is case sensitive, so you might want to lowercase all of your inputs. It'll output a score between 0 and 100 (100 being a very strong match). It's up to you how you filter out matches from there, maybe use a threshold: `if score > 75: its a match`.

I would recommend looking into the different functions in the `fuzzywuzzy` package, see what works best for you're case.

Comment: awesome, that seems exactly what I'm looking for. Could you just show a basic example from the above input/output using gensim and I'll accept the answer?

Comment: @Jar -- perfect, thank you. Out of curiosity at a very high-level, what are the differences between fuzzy and gensim? And which of the two would you suggest for the basic string comparison?

Comment: @David542 I haven't used gensim extensively, but from my understanding, its not used for string matching but rather capturing semantic meaning (ie `cat` and `dog` are similar because they are both animals). fuzzywuzzy is what you would use for string matching.

Comment: great, thanks for the detailed write-up and recommendations. Super helpful :) !!